# Do I tell time "by" the Sun, or "from" the Sun? Or both? And what about the shadows of the trees?

Tags: prepositions

So, I ran across this quote:

> Early men didn't have clocks. They told time by the sun and shadows of the trees.

And it provoked a doubt in me: I think I have heard native speakers use "tell time *from* the Sun", and here we have *by*.

So I went googling, and I found detailed articles on the subject, apparently written by native speakers, featuring both. In their headlines, even.

So, which is it?

1. [To tell the time **by** the Sun](http://www.education.com/science-fair/article/effective-sun-shadows-telling-time/)
2. [To tell the time **from** the Sun](http://creationtips.com/time.html)

Or is it both? And if so, are there any nuances, subtle shades of difference in meaning, between the two usages?

And speaking of shade, does the story change if the clock does? Do we tell time *by* or *from* the *shadows of the trees*?

Comment: For this native speaker, *by*. But if you want more formal answers, you're going to have to put more effort into your question. How did you try to answer this question for yourself? What did your research show?

Comment: I answered " by" but if both of them are possible there must be some difference between them just like " on time/ in time"

Comment: How did you research this question? What resources did you consult? What web searches did you try? What did you find? What didn't you find?

Comment: http://www.creationtips.com/time.html

http://www.education.com/science-fair/article/effective-sun-shadows-telling-time/

Comment: @SanjarIgamov Please [edit] additional material directly into the body of your question. Anything you put in the comments will likely get buried as time goes on. Also, you found your answer, not sure what else you want to know.

Comment: Early men didn't have clocks. They told time by/ from the sun and shadows of the trees.

Comment: @SanjarIgamov You're not shedding any more light here. The basic impediment here is we need you to [edit] your question -- not add further comments -- to describe, in detail, how you went about trying to figure out the answer to this question *before you asked here*. We need you to tell us, by [edit]ing, what research you conducted, how you conducted it, *what answers to your questions you found by doing that*, and just as critically, *what questions now remain*. The old adage still applies: we help those who help themselves.

Comment: The thing is I am confused and not able to make up my mind which preposition to use, I was going to use " by" but on the website I found the sentence with" from" that's why I am trying to clear it up.

Comment: @SanjarIgamov Ok, let me help. I'll show you what we are looking for, so you know how to ask questions appropriately in the future.

Comment: Now do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I meant "the story". Actually, what I really meant was "f$%# autocorrect".

Comment: I really think SE should award an "editor badge of the month" aka "how to save a condemned question/answer". You'd win with this one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't like to do it, honesty, I think it unfairly shifts the burden onto the regulars to provide good answers *and* ask all the good questions, but when I see a newcomer respond to feedback in good faith, show a willingness to interact on the site, esp when they seem at a loss due to a language barrier, I like to show them the ropes. But you're right about the links OP provided; that bit of effort was crucial. If he hadn't provided those, I would have walked away.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are correct. The use of *by* or *from* depend on your preconceived method of using the sun to tell the time, which is the 'silent part' (in brackets) of the example sentences below:

> ...tell the time *by* (looking at the position of) the sun...
>
> ...tell the time from (observing shadows cast by) the sun...

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that [*tell **the** time by the sun*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tell%20the%20time%20by%20the%20sun%22) and [*tell time by the sun*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tell%20time%20by%20the%20sun%22) both produce a couple of thousand hits in Google Books (the first article is very much an "optional extra"). Then consider...

[image]

That's not to say *to tell [the] time **from** the sun* is in any sense "incorrect" - it's just not a particularly common usage. But the choice of preposition doesn't affect the meaning.

I'll just add these usage figures from Google Books...

> *tell time **by** the sun* [(2250)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tell%20time%20by%20the%20sun%22)
>    *tell time **from** the sun* [(279)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tell%20time%20using%20the%20sun%22#tbm=bks&q=%22tell%20time%20from%20the%20sun%22)
>    *tell time **using** the sun* [(81)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tell%20time%20using%20the%20sun%22)

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that propositions are generally flexible.  They change over time, quickly. Is it *different **from** a tree* or *different **to** a tree? Based **on** Hamlet* or *based **off of** Hamlet? Based **in** Rome* or *based **out of** Rome?*